# Customizing OpenFileDialog

Tags: c#, winforms, openfiledialog, customizing

I am working on winforms application in C#. What I want to achieve is to get a file from user for which I am using the following code:

```
OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    string sFileName = dlg.FileName;
    //my code goes here
}
```

Now, everything is working fine but I want to put 3 radio buttons in the same dialog box, meaning I would now get two things from this dialog box

```
string sFileName = dlg.FileName; //same as in case of traditional dialog box
//some thing like this which tells which radio button is selected:
dlg.rbTypes.Selected
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: +1 for the question and answer(s). At least now I realise I don't want to move that much cheese. I'll find another way that doesn't  break the users' expectations of what is normal in Windows.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, that's possible, I did the same kind of customization with `SaveFileDialog`  successfully and it's pretty interesting.

Follow the following links:

> http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/OpenFileDialogEx.aspx
>
> http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/getsavefilename.aspx
>
> http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/CustomizeFileDialog.aspx

Also my own questions too will help you:

> [Change default arrangement of Save and Cancel buttons in SaveFileDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404278/change-default-arrangement-of-save-and-cancel-buttons-in-savefiledialog)
>
> [How to stop overwriteprompt when creating SaveFileDialog using GetSaveFileName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512752/how-to-stop-overwriteprompt-when-creating-savefiledialog-using-getsavefilename)

You have to use the `WinAPI` for this and you need to write the `ShowDialog` method in your own calling the `GetOpenFileName` windows function inside it, instead of calling .net's `OpenFileDialog`. The `GetOpenFileName` will create the windows `OpenFileDialog`. (Refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646927%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This together with writing the HookProc procedure and catching events such as `WM_INITDIALOG, CDN_INITDONE` inside it will help you do what you want.

To add radio buttons etc., you have to call the windows functions such as `CreateWindowEx` and `SendMessage`....

The 2nd link has the exact direction to the customization...

Ask for any clarifications...

Comment: What a pity that all code projects links are dead :(

Answer (score 3):

On XP you need to use the hook procedure method and the GetOpenFileName API. On Vista and later this will result in a horrid looking file dialog with limited utility, e.g. no search. On Vista you should use IFileDialog and to customise the dialog you need the IFileDialogCustomize interface. Because the new Vista dialogs are exposed as COM interfaces they are quite easy to consume in .net.