# How can i create an OpenFileDialog with Radiobuttons?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, radio-button, openfiledialog

Can someone tell me how can i create a OpenFileDialog window with Radiobuttons like this:

[image]

Thank for your answers !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093012/customizing-openfiledialog

Comment: try this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16276/Customizing-OpenFileDialog-in-NET