# C# WPF OpenFileDialog initial Focus in the list of files

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-7, openfiledialog

I have some basic code for opening an OpenFileDialog.

```
        OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
        dlg.DefaultExt = ".csv";
        dlg.Filter = "FileType|*.csv";
        dlg.Multiselect = false;
        bool? result = dlg.ShowDialog();
```

It works fine, but my Windows 7 users are complaining that the mouse scroll wheel doesn't scroll the list of files.  I think the reason for this is that the initial focus is on the text field for the file name.  If I click on the list of files, they become scrollable.  How can I set the initial focus in the OpenFileDialog to be the list of files instead of the textbox?

Comment: At a glance, maybe you can find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093012/customizing-openfiledialog it may be more than you wanted to actually do, though.

Comment: IIRC, you would have to pre-select a file by setting the FileName property, not often very practical.  Or recommend they update to Windows 10.

Comment: I couldn't replicate the problem, the scrool works pretty well here, win10, wich windows your users are using?

Comment: Wow.  Forgot that my development computer is a Win7.  Apparently, so is the one my customer is using.

Comment: but could you reproduce this behaviour?

Comment: I can't scroll without clicking on my Win7 machine.  I can on my Win10 machine.  My users have accepted this as an answer, but I'm still curious if it can be done on a Win7 machine.